# PPTP VPN Problem

Tags: linux, debian, vpn, pptp

I am using Debian OS with `pptpd`. My clients (both Windows and Mac) cannot complete the connection.

The following shows in syslog:

```
Jun  2 12:52:37 vpn pptpd[891]: MGR: Maximum of 6 connections available
Jun  2 12:52:48 vpn pptpd[892]: MGR: Launching /usr/sbin/pptpctrl to handle client
Jun  2 12:52:48 vpn pptpd[892]: CTRL: local address = 192.168.30.91
Jun  2 12:52:48 vpn pptpd[892]: CTRL: remote address = 192.168.30.50
Jun  2 12:52:48 vpn pptpd[892]: CTRL: pppd options file = /etc/ppp/pptpd-options
Jun  2 12:52:48 vpn pptpd[892]: CTRL: Client 192.168.28.154 control connection started
Jun  2 12:52:48 vpn pptpd[892]: CTRL: Received PPTP Control Message (type: 1)
Jun  2 12:52:48 vpn pptpd[892]: CTRL: Made a START CTRL CONN RPLY packet
Jun  2 12:52:48 vpn pptpd[892]: CTRL: I wrote 156 bytes to the client.
Jun  2 12:52:48 vpn pptpd[892]: CTRL: Sent packet to client
Jun  2 12:52:48 vpn pptpd[892]: CTRL: Received PPTP Control Message (type: 7)
Jun  2 12:52:48 vpn pptpd[892]: CTRL: Set parameters to 100000000 maxbps, 64 window size
Jun  2 12:52:48 vpn pptpd[892]: CTRL: Made a OUT CALL RPLY packet
Jun  2 12:52:48 vpn pptpd[892]: CTRL: Starting call (launching pppd, opening GRE)
Jun  2 12:52:48 vpn pptpd[892]: CTRL: pty_fd = 6
Jun  2 12:52:48 vpn pptpd[892]: CTRL: tty_fd = 7
Jun  2 12:52:48 vpn pptpd[892]: CTRL: I wrote 32 bytes to the client.
Jun  2 12:52:48 vpn pptpd[892]: CTRL: Sent packet to client
Jun  2 12:52:48 vpn pptpd[893]: CTRL (PPPD Launcher): program binary = /usr/sbin/pppd
Jun  2 12:52:48 vpn pptpd[893]: CTRL (PPPD Launcher): local address = 192.168.30.91
Jun  2 12:52:48 vpn pptpd[893]: CTRL (PPPD Launcher): remote address = 192.168.30.50
Jun  2 12:52:48 vpn pppd[893]: Plugin /usr/lib/pptpd/pptpd-logwtmp.so loaded.
Jun  2 12:52:48 vpn pppd[893]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
Jun  2 12:52:48 vpn pppd[893]: Using interface ppp0
Jun  2 12:52:48 vpn pppd[893]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/1
Jun  2 12:52:48 vpn pptpd[892]: GRE: Bad checksum from pppd.
Jun  2 12:52:48 vpn pptpd[892]: CTRL: Received PPTP Control Message (type: 15)
Jun  2 12:52:48 vpn pptpd[892]: CTRL: Got a SET LINK INFO packet with standard ACCMs
Jun  2 12:52:48 vpn pptpd[892]: GRE: accepting packet #1
Jun  2 12:52:51 vpn pptpd[892]: GRE: accepting packet #2
Jun  2 12:52:54 vpn pptpd[892]: GRE: accepting packet #3
Jun  2 12:52:57 vpn pptpd[892]: GRE: accepting packet #4
Jun  2 12:53:00 vpn pptpd[892]: GRE: accepting packet #5
Jun  2 12:53:03 vpn pptpd[892]: GRE: accepting packet #6
Jun  2 12:53:06 vpn pptpd[892]: GRE: accepting packet #7
Jun  2 12:53:09 vpn pptpd[892]: GRE: accepting packet #8
Jun  2 12:53:12 vpn pptpd[892]: GRE: accepting packet #9
Jun  2 12:53:15 vpn pptpd[892]: GRE: accepting packet #10
Jun  2 12:53:18 vpn pppd[893]: LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
Jun  2 12:53:18 vpn pptpd[892]: GRE: read(fd=6,buffer=610d20,len=8196) from PTY failed: status = -1 error = Input/output error, usually caused by unexpected termination of pppd, check option syntax and pppd logs
Jun  2 12:53:18 vpn pptpd[892]: CTRL: PTY read or GRE write failed (pty,gre)=(6,7)
Jun  2 12:53:18 vpn pptpd[892]: CTRL: Reaping child PPP[893]
Jun  2 12:53:18 vpn pptpd[892]: CTRL: Client 192.168.28.154 control connection finished
Jun  2 12:53:18 vpn pptpd[892]: CTRL: Exiting now
Jun  2 12:53:18 vpn pptpd[891]: MGR: Reaped child 892
```

Here is my pptpd-options file:

```
refuse-pap
refuse-chap
refuse-mschap
require-mschap-v2
require-mppe-128
proxyarp
nodefaultroute
lock
nobsdcomp
noipx
#mtu 1490
#mru 1490
```

When I watch the activity of the ppp0 interface which comes upon the connection, I see no activity at all.

Please advise.
Thanks !

Comment: `check option syntax and pppd logs`. Could you provide us pppd logs ?

Comment: You may want to add `debug` to your `pptpd-options` file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be a firewall problem.  Check that you are allowing the correct traffic into your VPN Server, specifically you need to permit `TCP 1723` and `Protocol 47 (GRE)` before `PPTP` will work correctly.  The problem you see in your log can be caused by `GRE` not being correctly relayed from your firewall.

You might also need to add `mppe-stateful` to your `pptpd-options` file to allow windows hosts.  Depending on how many intermediate `NAT` routers your connections may pass through you will need to reduce the `mru` and `mtu` settings.

Comment: It might also be a firewalling problem on the client's local network - try connecting from somewhere else if you can.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more about allowing `TCP 1723` and `GRE` ? I allowed them in my iptables. But still I am getting same error.

Answer (score 1):

Changing `/etc/ppp/pptpd-options` to the following options worked for me:

```
refuse-pap
refuse-chap
refuse-mschap
#require-chap
#require-mschap
#require-mschap-v2
#require-mppe-128
mppe-stateful
```